# How to connect sound and picture

Tags: javascript, html, image, audio

I have a task at hand and I can't figure out how to do. I am going to make a quiz where the player gets a sound and needs to guess the instrument by clicking a picture of it. To play the sound you press a button, which plays a random sound out of a selection of 5 sounds.

I need help connecting the picture to the sound so that when the player presses a picture, the page knows if it's correct or not.

Here is my HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1> Hvilket instrument lager lyden? </h1>
</header>

</br>
</br>
</br>

<div class="images">
  </br>
  </br>
  <img src="Vedlegg_V18/fagott.jpg" alt="Fagott bilde" onclick="">
  <img src="Vedlegg_V18/floyte.gif" alt="Fløyte bilde" onclick="">
  <img src="Vedlegg_V18/klarinett.jpg" alt="Klarinett bilde" onclick="">
  <img src="Vedlegg_V18/obo.jpg" alt="Obo bilde" onclick="">
  <img src="Vedlegg_V18/valthorn.jpg" alt="Valthorn bilde" onclick="">
</div>

</br>
</br>

<nav>
  <input type='button' value='Try Random Sound' onclick='playRandomSound();' />
  <span id='player'></span>
</nav>

<footer>
  <p> Laget av Sondre Hennie
</footer>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
var fagottEl = document.querySelector("#fagott");
var floyteEl = document.querySelector("#floyte");
var klarinettEl = document.querySelector("#klarinett");
var oboEl = document.querySelector("#obo");

var valthornEl = document.querySelector("#valthorn");

fagottEL.addEventListener("click", checkSound);
floyteEL.addEventListener("click", checkSound);
klarinettEL.addEventListener("click", checkSound);
oboEL.addEventListener("click", checkSound);
valthornEL.addEventListener("click", checkSound);


function playRandomSound(){
     var sounds = ["Vedlegg_V18/fagott.mp3",
                    "Vedlegg_V18/floyte.mp3",
                    "Vedlegg_V18/klarinett.mp3",
                    "Vedlegg_V18/obo.mp3",
                    "Vedlegg_V18/valthorn.mp3"];

     var soundFile = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
     document.getElementById("player").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundFile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
```

Any idea how to do this?
And also if you have any other tips, please tell me.

Comment: Use a mapper maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remember the correct answer by placing its variable in a higher scope.

Then, you can check if the id of the clicked button is the same as the random sound.

Finally, you can use audio tags and change the source, to play a sound - instead of using the embed tag.

HTML

```
<h2 id="feedback">Listen to the sound and click a button</h2>
<div id="fagott">fagott image</div>
<div id="floyte">floyte image</div>
<audio id="player" src="">
```

JS

```
let randomSound = ""
let fagottEl = document.querySelector("#fagott")
let floyteEl = document.querySelector("#floyte")
let sounds = ["fagott","floyte","klarinett","obo","valthorn"]
let player = document.getElementById("player")
let feedback = document.getElementById("feedback")

function chooseRandomSound(){
  randomSound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];

  player.src = "Vedlegg_V18/" + randomSound + ".mp3"
  player.play()
}   

fagottEl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  checkSound(e)
});

floyteEl.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  checkSound(e)
});

function checkSound(e){
  if(e.target.id == randomSound) {
    feedback.innerHTML = "Correct!"
  } else {
    feedback.innerHTML = "Wrong, it was a " + randomSound
  }
}

chooseRandomSound()
```

You can try the working code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0omjqea8/9/)

Comment: I treid it. Im sure it works, but I didn't get it to work anyway. Guess i puttet it in wrong in the pages. Woud you mind helping me more? Sorry for being such a noob

Comment: I cleaned up the code and put a working example on JSFiddle :)

Comment: thank you very much. I put it in. But didn't get it to work. Do you have time to just check for any mistakes of mine? This is my finished coding, and if there is anything missing I need to put in, pliz tell me. Appriciate it. Thank you! Here is the link to my version: https://jsfiddle.net/Triotrix/7awq30v6/9/. If you want the files I can send them to you

Comment: Your project was actually working, but you forgot to choose a random sound when the button is pressed. I cleaned your code up a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/7vL5ma9q/6/